# Numpy scalable diagonal matrices

Tags: python, numpy

Assuming I have the variables:

```
A = 3
B = 2
C = 1
```

How can i transform them into diagonal matrices in the following form:

```
np.diag([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])
Out[0]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

np.diag([0,0,0,1,1,0])
Out[1]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

np.diag([0,0,0,0,0,1])
Out[2]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

I would like this to be scalable, so for instance with 4 variables `a = 500, b = 20, c = 300, d = 200` the size of the matrix will be `500 + 20 + 300 + 200 = 1020`.
What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve even better performance by just allocating the array once, then setting the values all at once by specifying the indices. The indices are fortunately easy to obtain.

```py
import numpy as np

a = [3, 2, 1] # Put your values in a list
s = np.sum(a)
m = np.zeros((len(a), s, s), dtype=int) # Initialize array once
indices = (np.repeat(range(len(a)), a), *np.diag_indices(s, 2)) # Get indices
m[indices] = 1 # Set the diagonals at once
return m
```

Output:

```py
[[[1 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 1 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 1 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 1 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 1 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 1]]]
```

Comparing to @Ben Grossmann's answer, with `A=3000, B=2000, C=1000` and `100` repeats:

```py
def A():
    '''My solution'''
    a = [3000, 2000, 1000] # Put your values in a list
    s = np.sum(a)
    m = np.zeros((len(a), s, s), dtype=int) # Initialize array once
    indices = (np.repeat(range(len(a)), a), *np.diag_indices(s, 2)) # Get indices
    m[indices] = 1 # Set the diagonals at once
    return m

def B():
    '''Bens solution'''
    A = 3000
    B = 2000
    C = 1000

    n_list = [A,B,C]
    ab_list = np.cumsum([0] + n_list)
    ran = np.arange(ab_list[-1])
    return [np.diag(((a <= ran) & (ran < b)).astype('int')) for a,b in zip(ab_list[:-1], ab_list[1:])]

print(f'Timings:')
timeA = timeit.timeit(A, number=100)
timeB = timeit.timeit(B, number=100)
ratio = timeA / timeB
print(f'This solution: {timeA} seconds')
print(f'Current accepted answer: {timeB} seconds')
if ratio < 1:
    print(f'This solution is {1 / ratio} times faster than Bens solution')
else:
    print(f'Bens solution is {ratio} times faster than this solution')
```

Output:

```
Timings:
This solution: 1.6834218999993027 seconds
Current accepted answer: 5.096610300000066 seconds
This solution is 3.027529997086397 times faster than Bens solution
```

**EDIT:** Changed the "indices" algorithm to use `np.repeat` instead of `np.concatenate`.

Comment: You seem to have used 1,2,3 for A() and 1000,2000,3000 for B(). Repeating your experiment with with same A,B,C values indicates that your solution is a 3x speedup (rather than 1753x)

Comment: @BenGrossmann You are right, my bad. I copy pasted some changes without double checking. I'll fix it now. Thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach. The resulting array `mats` contains the matrices you're looking for.

```
A = 3
B = 2
C = 1

n_list = [A,B,C]
ab_list = np.cumsum([0] + n_list)
ran = np.arange(ab_list[-1])
mats = [np.diag(((a <= ran) & (ran < b)).astype('int')) 
        for a,b in zip(ab_list[:-1],ab_list[1:])]
for mat in mats:
    print(mat,'\n')
```

Result:

```
[[1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]] 

[[0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]] 

[[0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1]]
```

---

Edit: Here's a faster solution that yields the same result

```
n_list = [A,B,C]
ab_list = np.cumsum([0] + n_list)
total = ab_list[-1]
ran = np.arange(total)
mats = np.zeros((len(n_list),total,total))
for k,p in enumerate(zip(ab_list[:-1],ab_list[1:])):
    idx = np.arange(p[0],p[1])
    mats[k,idx,idx] = 1
for mat in mats:
    print(mat,'\n')
```

This seems to yield a ~10% speedup over the currently accepted solution

---

Another with roughly equivalent performance:

```
n_list = [A,B,C]
m = len(n_list)
ab_list = np.cumsum([0] + n_list)
total = ab_list[-1]
ran = np.arange(total)
mats = np.zeros((m,total,total))
idx = [k for a,b in zip(ab_list[:-1],ab_list[1:]) for k in range(a,b)]
mats[[k for k,n in enumerate(n_list) for _ in range(n)],
     idx,idx] = 1
for mat in mats:
    print(mat,'\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

The obligatory solution with [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), about ~2.25x slower than the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71116008/14277722) for the `[500,20,200,300]` arrays on a 2-core colab instance.

```
import numpy as np

A = 3
B = 2
C = 1

r = [A,B,C]
m = np.arange(len(r))
np.einsum('ij,kj->ijk', m.repeat(r) == m[:,None], np.eye(np.sum(r), dtype='int'))
```

Output

```
array([[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]])
```

Comment: Einsum always seems like black magic to me (especially when used this neatly)

Answer (score 1):

One posible method ( don't think it's optimal but it works):

```
import numpy as np

a = 3
b = 2
c = 1
values = [a,b,c] #create a list with values

n = sum(values) #calc total length of diagnal

#create an array with cumulative sums but starting from 0 to use as index
idx_vals = np.zeros(len(values)+1,dtype=int)
np.cumsum(values,out=idx_vals[1:]); 

#create every diagonal using values, then create diagonal matrices and 
#save them in `matrices` list
matrices = []
for idx,v in enumerate(values):

    diag = np.zeros(n)
    diag[idx_vals[idx]:idx_vals[idx]+v] = np.ones(v)
    print(diag)
    matrices.append(np.diag(diag))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another possibility:

```
import numpy as np

# your constants here
constants = [3, 2, 1] # [A, B, C]

size = sum(constants)
cumsum = np.cumsum([0] + constants)

for i in range(len(cumsum) - 1):
    inputVector = np.zeros(size, dtype=int)
    inputVector[cumsum[i]:cumsum[i+1]] = 1
    matrix = np.diag(inputVector)
    
    print(matrix, '\n')
```

Output:

```
[[1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]] 

[[0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]] 

[[0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1]]
```